# How to check max number of elements that are spaced evenly?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I have an array and my goal is to find out how many are spaced by multiples of 11. The array is NOT sorted.

```
Such as [27, 16, 52, 84], this would return 2
        [1, 55, 66, 33] should return 3.
        [99, 8, 52, 32] should return 0
```

Currently what I have is to basically run through for-each element in the array, check every other element with multiplying by 11. But this leaves me at a O(n²) runtime, anyway I can optimize this?

```
 static int eval(int [] a) {
       int i, j, k, counter = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                   for (k = -9; k < 10; k++) {
                        if (a[i] == a[j] + k*11) {
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
       }
     //if found nothing, will return 0, if found 1 matching, 
     //it should be 2 numbers that share this 11-difference. 
    return counter : counter == 0? 0: counter + 1;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yup. You have to check each pair one by one. Cannot go less than 2 loops.

Comment: But still - your first example has only 16 and 27. What's the other pair?

Comment: yeah i guess I should phrase it as "how many NUMBERS share difference of 11". 16 and 27 are 2 numbers, so 2

Comment: Useless comment, but I might have figured out a clever way to save time. Are your arrays about to be large? Because my idea will work better only on large arrays. Have to try it out first.

Comment: Array could be size of 4 to 6

Comment: A small optimization on the loops would be for i to only loop till a.length -1. Also let j start at i + 1 as you only need to check each pair of values once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the output is supposed to be for, say, `[11, 22, 34, 45]`. I'm interpreting the question as asking for the size of the largest subset of the input where all differences between elements of the subset are multiples of 11, and where size-1 subsets don't count.

All inputs with the same residue mod 11 are spaced by multiples of 11, so we only need to count how many ints in the input have each possible value of `i % 11`. This takes time linear in the size of the input.

```
static int eval(int[] a) {
    int[] inputsPerResidue = new int[11];
    for (int i : a) {
        inputsPerResidue[i % 11]++;
    }
    int maxGroupSize = 0;
    for (int groupSize : inputsPerResidue) {
        if (groupSize > 1 && groupSize > maxGroupSize) {
            maxGroupSize = groupSize;
        }
    }
    return maxGroupSize;
}
```

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks: It's not clear what you mean by that. The desired output in the problem statement makes no mention of returning the actual numbers that were spaced by multiples of 11; it only says to return a count.

Comment: my bad. lets just deleted these comments. :D

Answer (score 1):

You would need 2 loops to accomplish this. Calculate the difference between every element, and if that number is a multiple of 11, increment the counter. Return half the counter, as if you hit a multiple of 11 between two elements, you will end up hitting the same two elements again later in the loop:

```
 static int eval(int [] a) {
     int counter = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
             if (i != j && Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]) % 11 == 0) {
                 counter++;
             }
         }
     }
     return counter / 2;
 }
```